# ExtJS debbuging issue in jsfiddle

Tags: extjs

Trying to create an extjs app that reads csv data and parses it into a grid, I'm working from a prior jsfiddle that had a simple simpson grid now adding to it the data dynamically.
I've confirmed the csv data retrieval works and parsing it into a json format, I need assistance in how to debug this since the screen doesn't show any bug.
The fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/32nb4aey/

```
...
var result_data = parsetoJSON(parsed_result)


Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'nordanStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'department', 'login', 'status', 'email'],
    data: result_data
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Norda Tech User Data',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('nordanStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'First Name', dataIndex: 'firstname' },
        { text: 'Last Name', dataIndex: 'lastname' },
        { text: 'Department', dataIndex: 'department' },
        { text: 'Login', dataIndex: 'login' },
        { text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'status' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Why do you mean by "the screen"? Do you use Dev Tools? I get the following errors: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/32nb4aey/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://pluscolor.co.ke/static/users.csv'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." **and** "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://pluscolor.co.ke/static/users.csv'."

Comment: yes this was the issue